# OpenLayers print function not working

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Taking the function as in [Save google map as an image - using javascript (able to take screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733716/save-google-map-as-an-image-using-javascript-able-to-take-screenshot) , the solution ceased to work, as it is now generating an error on

```
var comp=transform.split(",");
```

It seems that the object returned by

```
$(".gm-style>div:first>div")
```

doesn't have the css property.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i got it to work using

```
 $(".olMapViewport>div:first>div").css("transform");
```

it seems that .gm-style may not work in some situations.